# Get amplitude of every audio frame of .wav [Python]

Tags: python, numpy, audio, scipy, librosa

I have a .wav file, and using python, I'd like to get a list of every audio frame where the amplitude is at the resting position. How could I achieve this? I think numpy, scipy or librosa could do such a thing, but I'm struggling to find exactly how to do it. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

**Update:** Apparently, [scipy.io.wavfile.read](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.io.wavfile.read.html) can do what I'm looking for – but I've been testing around with it and I haven't found anything too helpful.

[image: Visual Example]

Comment: Your figure shows a continuous example, which is not realistic in the digital context, because of sampling and quantization. When looking at samples you could simply look at `0` samples, but you will probably miss a lot of zero-crossing points because of sampling. So what you would need to do is to look at the sampled audio data and find those adjacent frame that have different signs.